# Is it needed a web service to connect to database if I connect on LAN and over VPN from the outside?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that has two libraries. The first one is a library that uses entity core to interact with the database. The second one is the business logic, that uses this first library. My idea is to use this two libraries in the clients, so I think I can save resources in the server where it is installed the database.

I know that if the database it is exposed to internet, to the public, because of security it is better to use a webserver, but if it is a database for internal use, so the clients will only connected if they are in the LAN or if they are outside, they will use OpenVpn to connect to the server and then they can connect to the database.

I also read that for performance reasons, a webservice can added a bit of overhead because of the serializarion process, so it is another reason so I was thinking that the clients could access to the database directly.

So in sumary, I would like to know if the connection will be in the LAN and over VPN, is it a bad idea to let to clients to connect to the database directly?

Thanks.

Comment: I have written several applications of this kind. In such a situation going via a web service adds a totally unnecessary level. Not only that, but normally the web server and the database server would be different machines, so you would be adding an extra layer of network traffic for no good reason.

Comment: This question is probably better suited on https://security.stackexchange.com/ . Allowing direct access from the client requires that you also completely trust the client. If a malicious user gets a hold of the application and can access the network, they could get free access to the database (I'm guessing the credentials for the DB access will be put in the client application).

Comment: Your question is opinion-based. Personally, I would opt for a web service for data access and business logic, with only the presentation layer on the client. This follows [n-tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) commonly used nowadays and can be used for both internal and public facing applications.